# WCF Windows authentication not working with wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, iis

Problem is that I cannot get windows authentication working with the wsHttpBinding.

This is the config:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="testbinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testbinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This is the response from the server when trying to call a method:
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate oXMwcaADCgEBomoEaGBmBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIDAH5XMFWgAwIBBaEDAgEepBEYDzIwMTcwODE2MjA1MjQwWqUFAgMK8G2mAwIBKakOGwxDT1JQLlNBQUIuU0WqGjAYoAMCAQGhETAPGw1jb3JwYXBwbDU5ODgk'.
Also there is a inner exception saying:
"The target principal name is incorrect"

I have setup a new site in IIS fresh for testing purposes with windows authentication enabled and Everything else disabled(I am not doing any ASP impersonation/double hop). Providers for windows authentication is Negotiate,Ntlm. Kernel mode authentication is enabled.
The application pool is running with a Active Directory service account.
The goal in the end is to use Kerberos for authentication but since it doesn't even work with Ntlm I have not started with the SPN and that stuff to get kerberos working yet.

It does however work if I change the application pool to be run with "ApplicationPoolIdentity" and not a AD service account?
I must have the app pool running with the AD service account.

If I change the config to:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="hbinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="basicHttpsBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="hbinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
```

It works fine(keeping the AD service account as well), why is that?
I dont wanna use basicHttpsBinding

I see a difference in the client config file (using the wcftestclient) that when using wshttp it has:

```
  <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="serviceaccount@contoso.com" />
  </identity>
```

Does it have something to do with this? (Just guessing wildly here)

The endpoint is https,IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side the generated identity tag was causing the issue

```
<identity>
  <userPrincipalName value="serviceaccount@contoso.com" />
</identity>
```

If i clear the value it works fine.
So i cleared that value in the web.config.
I can now setup kerberos and it works fine as well, gonna try setting the servicePrincipalName tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it depends on how is your domain set up, but you might try different type of Client credential type:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="testbinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testbinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Also, with wsHttpBinding there is negotiation that takes place behind the scene. Because the guidance on that negotiation is not specifically defined it makes sense sometimes to turn it off:

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="testbinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="testbinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

A Kerberos domain must exist for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't use Ntlm (due to security restrictions)
I managed to solve it (answer below)